# Dump and restore selected models/object graph in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given a MySQL database and a set of corresponding active record models similar to:

```
Test -< Categories -< Questions
```

I need a way to quickly dump the contents of Test #1 to a file, and then restore on a separate machine.  When Test #1 is reinstantiated in the database, all of the relational data should be intact (all foreign keys are maintained, the Categories, Questions for the test are all restored).  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer because I'm not sure it does exactly what you're asking, but you may want to look into: https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking of something that would allow me to cherry pick a specific set of objects as below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Jailer](http://jailer.sf.net) subsetting tool. It's for dumping subsets of relational data, keeping referential integrity.

Comment: I'll consider this the winner, since it lead me to the ruby gem http://exussum.heroku.com/projects/ocelot ... subsetting is the right term to search for

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using yaml: http://www.yaml.org/

It's an easy way to save and load heirarchical data (in a human readable format), and there are a number of implementations for Ruby.  They extend your classes, adding methods to save and load objects to and from yaml files.

I typically use it when I need to save and reload a "deep copy" of a large multi-level hash of objects.

Comment: Good point, I had considered going down this route, but hate having to color 15 classes with to_clone type methods

Answer (score 0):

There are options out there, [replicate](https://github.com/rtomayko/replicate) is outdates and known to have issues with Rails 4 and Ruby 2, [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) looks good, but doesn't have a -dump couterpart.